# How to bind key without prefix in TMUX?

Tags: tmux

By following lines in .tmux.conf:

```
set -g prefix C-a
bind a send-prefix
```

I set tmux global prefix to "C-a". And I can use "C-a a" to send "C-a" to a window.

Now I open an embeded tmux session (T2) in an tmux window of an existing tmux session (T1).
If I press "C-a c", a new window will be created in T1;
If I press "C-a a c", a new window will be created in T2.

It is tedious if I do a lot tmux actions in T2.

What I want is to bind another global prefix only to T2.
For example, I bind "C-b" as the global prefix for T2 and still use "C-a" as my prefix, then I'm able to use "C-a ***" to do T1 actions and use "C-b ***" to do T2 actions.

Someone has any ideas or walkaround?

Comment: You can set global prefix dynamically by selecting window B and type `tmux set -g prefix C-b` or through bash script.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a different key for the prefix.
I use the **`** key instead of the default **Ctrl+b**, which is saving some time in the long run.

This is part of my .tmux.conf to make this happen:

```
# use of ` instead of Ctrl+b
set-option -g prefix `
bind-key ` send-prefix
unbind-key C-b
```

Answer (score 1):

Tmux warns **against** creating nested sessions! Better avoid this workflow.

Answer (score 1):

- `bind-key -n <key-spec>`

or

- `bind-key -T root <key-spec>`

This is documented here:

`man --pager=less -p ' +Commands related to key bindings are as follows:' tmux`

> The root table is used for keys pressed without the prefix key: [...]

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a different `tmux.conf` file for that session [as stated here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343438/different-tmux-configs-for-different-sessions), you can also have different bindings for each session

```
tmux -f /path/to/tmux.conf
```